# How to Implement map, filter, fold in C++ 98

Tags: c++, functional-programming, c++98

I want to be able to do something like:

```
std::list<Person> personList;

std::list<Person> filteredPersonList;

Person filterByAge(Person p){
  if(p.age >= 18) return p;
}

filteredPersonList = filter(personList, filterByAge)
```

Comment: I can't spot any restriction regarding c++98 for [`std::list<>::remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/remove).

Comment: `std::transform`, `std::copy_if`, `std::accumulate`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `remove_copy_if`:

```
std::list<Person> personList;

std::list<Person> filteredPersonList;

Person filterByAge(Person p){
  if(p.age >= 18) return false;
}

std::remove_copy_if(personList.begin(), personList.end(), std::inserter(filteredPersonList, filteredPersonList.end()), filterByAge);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record:

```
template< 
        class IN_TYPE, 
        template < class IN_TYPE, class A = std::allocator< IN_TYPE > > class COLLECTION
> COLLECTION< IN_TYPE > filter (const COLLECTION< IN_TYPE >& collection, bool (*f) ( const IN_TYPE& ) )
{
    COLLECTION< IN_TYPE > result;

    typename COLLECTION< IN_TYPE >::const_iterator it;

    //std::copy_if( collection.begin(), collection.end(), result.begin(), f );
    for( it = collection.begin() ; it != collection.end() ; ++it )
    {
        IN_TYPE node = *it;
        bool passedFilter = f(node);

        if (passedFilter)
            result.push_back(node);
    }

    return result;
}
```